# error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine

Tags: plsql

I have a `SEARCH` package with several functions within that each return a `pipelined` table.

I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-06512: at "<SCHEMA_NAME>.SEARCH", line 955
ORA-06512: at "<SCHEMA_NAME>.SEARCH", line 216
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "<SCHEMA_NAME>.SEARCH", line 1143
ORA-06512: at line 1
29902. 00000 -  "error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine"
*Cause:    The execution of ODCIIndexStart routine caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages produced by the indextype code and
           take appropriate action.
```

The command that I use to get this error is:

```
 select * from table(search.user_search(10000003, '', 1, 20, 5, '', '', ''));
```

Here is the code around line 1143 of the `SEARCH` body:

```
FUNCTION USER_SEARCH(p_user_id number, p_search varchar2, p_page number, p_num_results number, p_concept_type_id number := null, p_standard_org varchar2 := null, p_standard_title varchar2 := null, p_standard_number varchar2 := null) RETURN SEARCH_RESULTS_TABLE AS

v_sub char(1);

v_rtn search_results_table := search_results_table();

v_user_id number;

v_page number;
v_num_results number;

v_query varchar2(4000);

cursor c_concept is
  select * from table(search.concept_new(v_user_id, v_query, v_page, v_num_results, p_concept_type_id, p_standard_org, p_standard_title, p_standard_number));

BEGIN
  v_page := p_page;
  v_num_results := p_num_results;

  v_query := p_search;

  if (v_query = '') then

    v_query := null;

  end if;

  -- ONLY DURING DEVELOPMENT
  v_user_id := p_user_id;

  if v_user_id = 0 then
    v_user_id := 2;
  end if;


  if v_page = null then
    v_page := 1;
  end if;

  if v_num_results = null then
    v_num_results := -1;
  end if;

  select security.has_permission(p_user_id, 'UNLIMITED_RESULTS') into v_sub from dual;

  case v_sub
    when 'N' then
      v_rtn := search.term(v_user_id, p_search, 1, 20, P_concept_type_id, p_standard_org, p_standard_title, p_standard_number);
    when 'Y' then
      for r_concept in c_concept loop -- line 1143
        v_rtn.extend;

        v_rtn(v_rtn.last) := search_results_row(r_concept.SCORE, r_concept.FROM_TABLE, r_concept.ID, r_concept.IN_DICTIONARY);
      end loop;
  end case;

  return v_rtn;

END USER_SEARCH;
```

The code around line 216:

```
FUNCTION CONCEPT_NEW(p_user_id number, p_search varchar2, p_page number := 1, p_num_results number := -1, p_concept_type_id number := null, p_standard_org varchar2 := null, p_standard_title varchar2 := null, p_standard_number varchar2 := null) RETURN SEARCH_RESULTS_TABLE PIPELINED AS

  out_rec search_results_row := search_results_row(null,null,null,null);

  v_num_pages number;
  v_num_results number;

  cursor c_count is
    select count(*) cnt, ceil(count(*) / p_num_results) num_pages from (
    select * from (
    select rownum rn, bb.* from (
      select * from (
        select sum(score) score, concept_id from
        (
          (
            select 
              sum(score) score,
              concept_id
            from
            (
              select
                s.score + (case
                when c.eotd = 'N' then
                  200
                else 
                  0
                end) score,
                ct.concept_id
              from
                table(search.synonym_search(p_search)) s,
                term_synonym ts,
                concept_term ct,
                concept c
              where
                c.eotd = 'N' and
                s.table_id = ts.synonym_id and
                ts.term_id = ct.term_id and
                c.concept_id = ct.concept_id
            )
            group by
              concept_id
          )
          union all
          (
          select 
            sum(score) score,
            concept_id
          from
          (
            select
              s.score + (case
              when c.eotd = 'N' then
                200
              else 
                0
              end) score,
              cd.concept_id
            from
              table(search.definition_search(p_search)) s,
              concept_definition cd,
              concept c
            where
                c.eotd = 'N' and
              s.table_id = cd.definition_id and
              c.concept_id = cd.concept_id
          )
          group by
            concept_id
          )
        )
        group by concept_id
      ) order by score desc
    ) bb) where score > 100) where rn < 1000;

    -- another cursor here called c_search (removed for cleanliness)

    v_added boolean;

    v_in_dict varchar(1);

    v_concept_id number;

    cursor c_in_dict is
      select * from dictionary_concept where concept_id = v_concept_id and dictionary_id in (select dictionary_id from company_dictionary where client_company_id in (select client_company_id from users where users_id = p_user_id));

    v_in_dict_result c_in_dict%rowtype;  

BEGIN

  open c_count;

  fetch c_count into v_num_results, v_num_pages; -- line 216

  close c_count;

  out_rec.SCORE := v_num_results;
  out_rec.FROM_TABLE := 'HEADER';
  out_rec.ID := v_num_pages;
  out_rec.IN_DICTIONARY := 'N';

  pipe row(out_rec);

  -- more code here but been removed

  RETURN;

END CONCEPT_NEW;
```

The code around line 995:

```
FUNCTION STANDARD_SEARCH(p_search varchar2) RETURN RESULT_TABLE 
PIPELINED
AS

  out_rec result_type := result_type(null, null);

  cursor c_search is
    select 
      45 score,
      source_id
    from
      source
    where
      source_title = p_search or
      standard_number = p_search
    union all
    select
      40,
      source_id
    from
      source
    where
      lower(source_title) = lower(p_search) or
      lower(standard_number) = lower(p_search)
    union all
    select
      35,
      source_id
    from
      source
    where
      lower(source_title) like lower(p_search) || '%' or
      lower(standard_number) like lower(p_search) || '%'
    union all
    select
      30,
      source_id
    from
      source
    where
      lower(source_title) like '%' || lower(p_search) || '%' or
      lower(standard_number) like '%' || lower(p_search) || '%'
    union all
    select
      10 * contains(source_title, lower(p_search)),
      source_id
    from
      source
    where 
      contains(source_title, lower(p_search)) > 1
    union all
    select
      10 * contains(standard_number, lower(p_search)),
      source_id
    from
      source
    where 
      contains(standard_number, lower(p_search)) > 1;

BEGIN

  for r_search in c_search loop -- line 995

    out_rec.SCORE := r_search.SCORE;
    out_rec.TABLE_ID := r_search.SOURCE_ID;

    pipe row(out_rec);

  end loop;

  return;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `= null` to `is null`.  Zero-length strings in Oracle are already NULL so `= ''` is also incorrect.

Those are some obvious bugs but the code is so complex I'm not sure if they are directly related to the errors.  You may need to shrink your code down until it can fit inside a small, reproducible test case.  That can take hours of work sometimes.

Another suggestion is to rethink whether you need to use pipelined functions.  In my experience pipelined functions are buggy and over-used.  Sometimes they can be replaced by regular SQL statements.   Sometimes they can be replaced by a simpler function that returns a complete collection, instead of returning it one row at a time.  Unless the collection is so ginormous that it can't reasonably fit in memory, or you need the function to return the first N results so they can be processed immediately, the pipelined feature doesn't help.